# style属性を変更しているJavaScriptコードの場所を調べるには？

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging

Chromeデベロッパーツールにおいて、JavaScriptからCSSを編集した場合にelement.styleに結果が表示されますが、JavaScriptの該当行を知るにはどうしたらよいのでしょうか。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

添付画像のelement.styleが外部JavaScriptのどこから（何行目において）設定（記述）されているものなのか知りたく、ご教授いただけますと幸いです。
どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### 開発者ツールのブレークポイント機能を使う

変更が行われる要素が事前に特定できるなら、開発者ツールでその要素を右クリックして、Break on... > attribute modifications としてブレークポイントを貼ることができます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

HTMLが変わらなければ、リロードしてもブレークポイントは残ります。

### MutationObserver を使う

[MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) を使うと、指定したDOM要素が変更されたときにコールバックを実行することができます。コールバックの中に `debugger;` でブレークポイントを張ったり、`console.trace()` などを実行することで、変更を発生させたコードを調べることができます。

次のようにsubtreeオプションを使うことで、ドキュメント全体を監視することも可能です。

```js
function hoge() {
  const body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
  body.style.backgroundColor = '#abc';
}

// MutationObserverの作成・登録
const observer = new MutationObserver(_ => console.trace());
observer.observe(document, {
  attributes: true,
  subtree: true,
  attributeFilter: ['style']
});

hoge();
```

注意点として、このコールバックは非同期に呼び出されるため、Sourcesタブの右パネルでAsyncにチェックをつけておかないと、非同期呼び出し元のコールスタックが表示されません。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

（変更が発生する前であれば）MutationObserverの作成・登録はコンソールで行っても大丈夫です。次のようにワンライナーにしてもいいですね。

```
new MutationObserver(_ => console.trace()).observe(document, {attributes: true, subtree: true, attributeFilter: ['style']})
```

参考

- [Detect element style change in chrome - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13566346/2818869)
- [How do you get a stack trace for a triggered MutationObserver? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31428249/2818869)

Comment: 極めてご丁寧に回答いただきありがとうございます！！！！！はじめてやることが多いのでひとつひとつ試してみますー！！！！！