# Firefoxを使用して要素を自動的に生成してるJS機能を特定する

Tags: javascript, firefox

ロード済みのHTMLページですが、その後に自動的に生成される要素があります。
その要素を生成してるJS機能を特定して削除したいですが、Firefoxの開発ツールでできますでしょうか？

Firefoxのバージョン：53.0.3

Comment: fifefoxの開発ツールとはfirebugのようなサード・パーティのプラグインでもOKですか？

Comment: 質問内容は、JavaScript の該当個所を「特定」するまでの方法という事でよろしいですか？ それとも JavaScript を削除する方法も含んでいますか？（その場合、もう少し情報が必要です。サーバー側の実装を変更する話なのか、UserScript 的な物で自分のクライアントサイドだけ変更できればよい話なのか、などです。）

Comment: Firefoxにこだわらない（特定が目的）であれば[Cromeでの回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/32295/5044)が使える(subtree変更)と思います。

Answer (score 0):

開発者ツールを起動して、消したいスクリプトを右クリックして「ノードを削除」すればいいと思いますが、それでは実現できませんか？

[image: FFの開発者ツール]

Comment: それだけですと次ロードしたらまた出ますでしょう？これからもう出ないようにソースから削除したいです。

Comment: 画面をロードすると、サーバーにリクエストが送信され、JavaScriptを含むレスポンス(HTML)が返ってきます。なので、サーバーサイドの実装を直さないとどうすることもできません。

Comment: こちらでサーバーの管理していますのでそれ大丈夫ですよ。だが、どこのファイルを改造していいか分からなくて困っています。

Comment: どのJavaScriptか特定できていないのであれば、現在のページで使用しているJavaScriptのコードを開発者ツールで表示できるので、そのコード内を「自動的に生成される要素」をキーワードにして検索してみれば見つかると思います。

Comment: Googleで検索するのですか？

Comment: Googleではないです。デバッガータブでJavaScriptのコードを確認できると思いますが、そのコード内を検索しても見つかりませんか？

Comment: 要素のIDですか？デバッガータブで検索してみましたが見つからないので思い当たらないです。